# Serialize error with jms sirialize bundle in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I use symfony 3  with jms serialize bundle. How to serialize an exception/error which has stack trace to JSON for sending it to client? [An exception screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkw9l.png)
[image]

Helper for generating an exception:

```
namespace Bundle\DependencyInjection;
use Exception;

class UnknownException extends Exception
{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct('An unknown exception occurred', 500, null);
    }
}
```

I create an exception inside a contoller:

```
$error= new UnknownException()
```

And then I send it:

```
$serializedError = $this->serializer->serialize( // it is jms serializer
    $error,
    'json'
);

$response = new Response();
$response
    ->setStatusCode($statusCode)
    ->setContent($serializedError)
    ->send();
```

I recieves an error on client: `Resources are not supported in serialized data`

I think it occurres because the exception trace is a very huge structure: [An example screenshot of exception trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mt3ec.png)
[image]

So, how to serialize it? How to serialize huge structures with jms serializer?

Comment: did you try annotating your exception with any ExclusionPolicy?

Comment: No, I didn't. But the default error of Symfony has a stack trace which is printed to user. So I don't want to exclude the stack trace at all, I want to serialise it to send to the client in JSON. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found this gist: 
https://gist.github.com/Thinkscape/805ba8b91cdce6bcaf7c
and manage to serialize exceptions. It's not a problem about how huge is or how complex, but some fields are unserializable (like closures or streams).

I put my exceptions in a containing class and within that class a pre-serialize hook:

```
class ErrorList
{
    /**
     * registrazione di eventuali errori
     *
     * @SWG\Property()
     *
     * @JMS\Type("ArrayCollection<ServiceCore\lib\exception\JsonableException>")
     *
     * @var ArrayCollection<ServiceCore\lib\exception\JsonableException>
     */
    protected $errors;

    /**
     * @JMS\PreSerialize
     */
    public function serialize()
    {
        foreach ($this->errors as $error) {
            JsonableException::flattenExceptionBacktrace($error);
        }
    }
}
```

while `JsonableException` extends `Exception` with function from gist:

```
class JsonableException extends \Exception
{

    public static function flattenExceptionBacktrace(\Exception $exception)
    {
         // file_put_contents("/tmp/dump.log", print_r(get_object_vars($this), true));
         $traceProperty = (new \ReflectionClass('Exception'))->getProperty('trace');
         $traceProperty->setAccessible(true);

         $flatten = function (&$value, $key) {
            if ($value instanceof \Closure) {
                $closureReflection = new \ReflectionFunction($value);
                $value = sprintf(
                    '(Closure at %s:%s)',
                    $closureReflection->getFileName(),
                    $closureReflection->getStartLine()
                );
            } elseif (is_object($value)) {
                $value = sprintf('object(%s)', get_class($value));
            } elseif (is_resource($value)) {
                $value = sprintf('resource(%s)', get_resource_type($value));
            }
         };

        do {
            $trace = $traceProperty->getValue($exception);
            foreach ($trace as &$call) {
                array_walk_recursive($call['args'], $flatten);
            }
            $traceProperty->setValue($exception, $trace);
        } while ($exception = $exception->getPrevious());
                $traceProperty->setAccessible(false);
    }
}
```

i try also using a `JMS\HandlerCallback` in `JsonableException` class, but no success in that direction.